# Scope property not updated when bound to $state property

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Using UI Router 0.2.12. Why `$rootScope.$state` bound to the `$state` object itself updates the expression in HTML (when changing UI states):

```
// index.html:
<!-- the JSON output is updated when transitioning to a new state -->
<div>Current state data: {{ $state.current.data | json }}</div>

// app.js:
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.controller('AppController',
  function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state; // <-- works
  }
);
```

But, binding to one of the properties of the $state object doesn't:

```
// index.html:
<!-- the JSON output stays the same when transitioning to a new state -->
<div>Current state data: {{ $state.data | json }}</div>

// app.js:
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router'])
.controller('AppController',
  function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state.current; // <-- doesn't work
  }
);
```

Thank you.

Comment: well, while **`$state`** is a *factory* *(configured provider in fact)* the **.current** is just a runtime value. we should use `$state` to be referenced in the `$rootScope`

Comment: I've edited the examples to move the code from a `run` block to a `controller`. Just want to clarify that by `doesn't work` I meant that the expression in HTML doesn't get updated.

Comment: @RadimKöhler Did I understand correctly that by doing `$state.current` I actually decouple a runtime object from the `$state` singleton and assign it to a scope variable. So, when `$scope.current` gets updated, the scope variable still references the original object with the original values?

Comment: YEAAAAH. Exactly.. just keep referencing the FACTORY. That is the way how to share stuff.. and access it $state.current. that should work ;)